# Angular: $scope.$watch a nested collection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, watch

In my Angular app, I have a checkbox list which is generated via a nested ng-repeat, like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="type in boundaryPartners">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 highlight top-pad">
            <div ng-repeat="partner in type.partners" class="highlight">
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="partner"
                    ng-model="ids[$parent.$index][$index]"
                    ng-true-value="{{partner}}"
                    ng-false-value="{{undefined}}">
                    <p><span ></span>{{partner.name}}<p>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in my controller:

```
$scope.ids = [];

$scope.$watchCollection('ids', function(newVal) {
    for (var i = 0, j = newVal.length; i < j; i++) {

        // Create new participatingPatners tier if it doesn't exist
        if(!$scope.report.participatingPartners[i]) $scope.report.participatingPartners[i] = {};

        // Give it an id
        $scope.report.participatingPartners[i].id = i + 1;

        // Map our values to it
        $scope.report.participatingPartners[i].entities = $.map(newVal[i], function(value, index) {
            return [value];
        });
    }

});
```

The problem is, this `$scope.$watchCollection` stops watching once I've added one of each top-level `ids`, so if I add a given number of inputs from the first nested list, then another from the second list, My `$scope.report.participatingPartners` object never gets updated.

How can I `$watch` for changes within `ids[$parent.$index][$index]`, making sure updated my object whenever a checkbox gets ticket or unticked?

Comment: Create a demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue). Suspect problem is due to `ng-model` needing to create nested arrays and might be better as object ... or use `ng-change`

Comment: I really wouldn't rely on `$index` values to bind to other model properties like this.  `$index` doesn't represent any tangible value tied to the item, it only represents the index that the item holds within this view.  If the view changes (items added, removed, reordered, etc), this index changes dynamically, making other items referencing it suddenly reference some other object.  You should organize your data in your controller instead, or at least provide your own unique index that references the object, not it's view placement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an array of arrays:

```
$scope.ids = [
  [],
  [],
  //...
]
```

But use `$watchCollection` to watch for changes in the outer array, i.e. of `$scope.ids`. This will only identify changes when nested arrays become different objects (or created the first time).

You *could* use `$scope.$watch("ids", function(){}, true)` - with `true` standing for "deep-watch", but that would be very wasteful, since it's an expensive check that would be performed on every digest cycle, whether a checkbox was clicked or not.

Instead, use `ng-change` to trigger the handler:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="partner"
       ng-model="ids[$parent.$index][$index]"
       ng-change="handleCheckboxChanged()">
```

```
$scope.handleCheckboxChanged = function(){

  // whatever you wanted to do before in the handler of $watchCollection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$watchCollection` is similar to `$watch` in that it checks the physical object reference, but goes one step further; it also goes one level deep and does a reference check on those properties.

You'll need to use `$watch`, but set the objectEquality flag to true. This will tell `$watch` to perform deep reference checking. Depending on the depth of the item being watched this can hurt performance significantly.

`$watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);`

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to watch for object equality :

```
$scope.$watchCollection('ids', function(newVal) {

}, true);
```

Comment: `$watchCollection` doesn't have a 3rd parameter that you identified as "object equality". Did you mean `$watch`?